# Gravity and rotating torus

Tags: gravity, velocity, rotational-kinematics

Questions:
Would a spinning torus lose its weight?
Would a solid torus, spinning at 7,81 km/s radial speed completely loose it's weight on Earth-like object?
Would it 'fly away' at higher speeds?
{Everywhere bellow torus lay flat on surface of Earth and spins around vertical axe through its center}

Thoughts:
I think it should as we live in bent space at you should apply force to anything that moves faster than escape velocity to keep it on Earth.

Characteristics of our bent space are: 7,81 km/s - first cosmic speed and 9.8 m/c^2 is gravitational acceleration of our planet.

This means than in 7,81km our planet curves by 9,8m. Meaning that if body will travel that distance faster it will end up higher, relative to surface and you should apply force to keep it same height at start point. This force will be aligned with gravitational pull and compensate for it (opposite direction).

Take bent space there should be 3 forces in rotating torus accounted for:
1.  Gravitational pull, constantly pulling every part of torus
2.  Rotational pull. Compensated by torus’s material strength
3.  Apparent force due to curved space and high speed
(well could be that forces 1 and 3 are same force – according to Einstein)

In my thought experiment I ignoring other forces, such as Earth spin, rotation around Sun and Moon rotation. Also I presume torus made out of material impossible to break. But hey, it is just hypothetically.

Conclusion:
If mentioned above is true and spinning object will tend to fly away from gravitational pull of other body than it is possible to make ‘gravitational propeller’ for small objects like asteroids and tag them to other orbits. The possibilities are huge.

Comment: Are you asking if a rapidly spinning torus will levitate?

Comment: No, you need 7,81 km/s radial speed (in the "up" direction) of the center of mass of an object for it to escape earths gravity. What makes you think a torus specifically can do what other spinning objects can't?

Comment: No, you do not have to be in 'up' direction - near orbit satellites

Comment: No, you do not have to be in 'up' direction - near orbit satellites moving parallel to surface and yet remain stationary relative to ground as if they fall over horizon. The thing is if you travel at 7,81 km/s you should always be at the same height - hence 'weight loss' as nothing pushes down and rather remain 'hanging in the air'. With faster speed weight will tend to be higher than previous point and it will have 'negative' weight. If every part of torus span to 7.81 km/s (say with radius 10km) will try to be higher than before - would not whole thing tend to lose its weight?

Comment: Think about - "you need 7,81 km/s radial speed (in the "up" direction) of the center of mass of an object for it to escape earths gravity" - if, hypothetically, you traveling at 5 m/s slow speed from the Earth sooner or later you'll end up far from Earth's gravity without have to go 7.81 km/s. This 7.81 speed means traveling at near Earth's surface you wont fall on it. Lower speed - you'll fall and faster - you'll fly away from it (and actually you will apply some force to stay on Earth)

Comment: Totally confusing. Draw your geometry to make it clear. If torus is so strong as to be rigid, none of the above matters.

Comment: The setting is totally confusing. Please consider improving the explanation by adding some more details, perhaps supply mathematical formulas to support your claims and enrich the discussion.

Comment: Guys, I've got no drawing soft on this comp but I might try to explain with other words. Again presume you have two vertical walls parallel to each other but few miles apart.

Comment: Guys, I've got no drawing soft on this comp but I might try to explain with other words. Again presume you have two vertical walls parallel to each other but few miles apart. And you have ball traveling from wall to wall. Lets say this 'mathematical' ball have no inertion and as soon it touches the opposite wall it bouce back with same speed at angle it hit the wall(no air too).

Comment: At speed lower than first cosmic it will descend every bounce. At first cosmic it will bounce indefenetly at same height and at faster speeds it will bounce each time higher. But we do not want for ball to escape so we slightly bend these walls one one the left - clockwise and on the right counterclockwise so each time ball did not go up but bounced off the walls at same level.

Comment: So every time ball bounce of this 'bent' wall it will produce small force upwards (along with much bigger sidewise force) equell to force nesserary to lower ball down. If this walls are attached to each other and have small weight - every bounce will try to kick whole system up (for argument sake we'll have two balls hitting opposite sides simultaniously - to compensate fo side kick).
This does not violate any phisical laws known and I just want to share my thoughts

Comment: Last night I thought how to explain issue and came up with this explanation: Say you standing on the Earth (no air etc) and you weight 100kg (well I do). The second you'll start walking your weight will decrease (by very tiny) in weight due to centrefugial force from Earth.
The faster you'll move the lighter you'll be. Presume I hold in one hand string (say 100m long) and another end attached to the pole sticking from the ground. I'll get 2 centrifugal forces: a) around Earth as I travel on the surface and b)around pole as I walk in circle.

Comment: To make it more dynamic lets remove the pole and instead of it I'll have a friend who holding that string and walks in same direction but opposite side - so I pull him and he pulls me in balance. I'm saying that if we'll reach first cosmic speed we'll have a huge tension on the string and... we'll lose weight!
We wont be touching ground anymore. Give it a higher speed and our weight will become negative - hence levitation. Feels not right but I do not see where I'm wrong! Please correct me if someone know where I'm mistaken or confirm my suspicion.